# Only the URL changes when clicking on link with ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently learning ionic and i am trying to create a basic app. My problem is when i click on the links in the app it doesn't change to the template in the link it only changes the URL.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-bar>

      <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
   });
})

// states for each page
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');

$stateProvider

// main page that first loads, select region page
.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
        templateUrl: 'templates/regions.html',
        controller: 'regionCTRL'
  })
// EU page
.state('app.EU', {
    url: '/EU',
    views: {
      'Regions': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/EU.html',
        controller: 'APICtrl'  
      }
    }
  })
// USCAN page
.state('app.USCAN', {
    url: '/USCAN',
    views: {
      'Regions': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/USCAN.html',
        controller: 'APICtrl'
        }
    }
  })
})
```

regions.html template

```
<!-- user can select which region they want to see -->
<ion-view view-title="Regions">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list id="item">
            <ion-item href="#/app/EU">
                <p>EU</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#">
                <p>ASPAC</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#/app/USCAN">
                <p>USCAN</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#">
                <p>EAGM</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#">
                <p>LATAM</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#">
                <p>CHINA</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#">
                <p>INDIA</p>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the state, the ui-sref directive is the correct way to go:

```
    <ion-item ui-sref="/app/EU">
        <p>EU</p>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: To build on this answer you can also do it by state name e.g. `ui-sref="app.EU"`

Comment: When i use the ui-sref all that changes is the url, the page itself doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Few days back i had pushed my code to my [repository](https://github.com/amoebageek/ionicApp) you can get the idea form here.

[Routing Menue](https://github.com/amoebageek/ionicApp/blob/master/www/templates/menue.html#L17)

Defined [State](https://github.com/amoebageek/ionicApp/blob/master/www/js/app.js#L29)

Its required that you keep your snippets inside ionic-content like [i did here](https://github.com/amoebageek/ionicApp/blob/master/www/templates/courses.html#L1)

```
<ion-view title="courses" hide-back-button="true" left-buttons="leftButtons" right-buttons="rightButtons"
      hide-back-button="true">

    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
        ----your elements----
    </ion-content >
```